# vertically align fontawesome icon to the middle of a textarea

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am using skeleton css framework, I want to vertically align my fontawesome icon to the right of a textarea, but it seems the common "vertical-align:middle; display: table-cell;" doesn't work. I also want when the textarea resizes, the icon still aligns in the middle, without hard code a height inside the style, is it possible?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<style type="text/css">
.icon {
margin-left: 1em;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
    <label for="inputA">labelA</label>
    <textarea class="u-full-width" id="inputA" type="text"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="one colum">  
    <span class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to fake it, due to the way skeleton styles its columns.

As such, you can use absolute positioning to offset the icon as necessary:

```css
.six.columns {
  position: relative; /* <-- ensure the icon positions relative to the parent column */
}
#inputA {
  margin-bottom: 0; /* <-- remove the textarea margin, making the icon look like its not centered */
}
.icon {
  position: absolute; /* <-- position the icon */
  /* transform:translateY(-50%); OPTIONAL, use for true vertical alignment */
  top: 50%;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
    <label for="inputA">labelA</label>
    <textarea class="u-full-width" id="inputA" type="text"></textarea>
    <span class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="one column">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This becomes a problem however when you enlarge the textarea sideways.

Comment: @user1129884 - this is because of the way resizing works on textarea elements within the other styling context. If you are allowing for horizontal resizes, you should move away from the rigid column structure

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a javascript function wich reubicates the icon. Anyways, it could be a little bit of trouble if you're handling with many dinamic icons/textareas.

css:

```
.icon {
  margin-left: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  position:absolute;  <--- additions
  padding-top:52px;   <--- additions
  padding-left:269px; <--- additions
}
```

HTML (Notice the `onClick="resiz()"` instruction)

```
<textarea onClick="resiz()" class="u-full-width" id="inputA" type="text"></textarea>
<span id="ico" class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> </span>
```

JavaScript

```
document.resiz=function(){

    var he = document.getElementById("inputA").offsetHeight;
    var wi = document.getElementById("inputA").offsetWidth;

    document.getElementById("ico").style.paddingTop=(he/2+20)+'px';
    document.getElementById("ico").style.paddingLeft=wi+'px';
}
```

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ko2dzcfc/

You can also make the resiz() instruction to execute when the page loads, so it will automatically place the icon correctly at start, and avoid editing the css.

Update: I tested it in Firefox, and it worked well. In chromium it does not work so well. Maybe you'll have to edit the code for differents browsers